# InnoDB index size with NULLs allowed (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, innodb

I wonder if anyone ever found confirmation in MySQL docs that for InnoDB, a column that allows NULL in the index takes 1 extra byte?

Example: create a column `SMALLINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL;` (2 bytes). The index uses 3 bytes (without taking into account PK links).

The same column that does not allow NULL: `SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL`; The index will be as it should - 2 bytes.

UPD: I found this in docs:
"Due to the key storage format, the key length is one greater for a column that can be NULL than for a NOT NULL column."
But still, I dont understand, whether index size is 1 byte greater with NULLable column or not.

P.S. Sorry for my bad English :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several flaws in the `key_len` of `EXPLAIN`.

- There are differences between Engines, but Explain does not take account of such.
- The null bit may or may not take a full byte.  Still, 3 vs 2 is a handy clue that the `SMALLINT` is `NULL` or `NOT NULL`.
- `VAR...` actually takes a variable amount of space.
- InnoDB` has a 1- or 2-byte prefix to each column; that is not mentioned.
- The `key_len` *usually* accounts for any column(s) that are tested with `=`.  If there also a "range" test (`BETWEEN`, `>`, `LIKE 'foo%', etc)` that can use part of the index, key_len does not indicate such.
- Ditto for using part of the index for `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.

You can get *more* information (but still not 'everyting') by using `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`.

Logically, *if not in reality*, there is no room for `NULL` in a 2-byte `SMALLINT`.  So, more space is needed -- at least one bit.

There are two separate issues -- The size of the index BTree, and the data structure(s) used during the query.

I would argue that the extra byte or bit for `NULL` is not worth worrying about.  Instead, it is better to say `NOT NULL` except when you have a "business logic" requirement for `NULL` (no value, N/A, not yet specified, etc, etc).  Then let the table, index, etc, consume an extra bit or byte as needed.

I think (without sufficient confirmation) that InnoDB takes no extra space for the null bit -- it is one of the 8 or 16 bits that prefixes each column.

Note that in InnoDB, an index BTree is essentially identical to the data BTree.  (And the `PRIMARY KEY` is the ordering of the data BTree.)